# argumentparser ignore second character in space

Tags: python, argparse

I have the below code

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Generates calculations from input files')
 parser.add_argument('-c', '--by-client', action = 'store_true', help = 'Output issues broken down by client')
 parser.add_argument('-cn', '--client-name',  help = 'Generate output by client name provided', default=None)
```

When I am running the script and giving option like `-cn` it's throwing an error

```
error: argument -c/--by-client: ignored explicit argument 'n'
```

Strangely it was working before, but at sudden it stopped working.

Comment: It probably worked until you added `-c`. After that, argparse attempts to split multiple characters after a single dash into separate flags.

Comment: What happens if you rename `-c` to `-cl`?

Comment: When was this 'before'?  A while back the 'allow_abreviations'  parameter was added, and for a while it messed with the chaining of single dash arguments.  But I think that's corrected.  '-c' being a store_true', can be chained, and this '-cn'  could be confused for a chained.  It's best not to used flags like '-cn'

Comment: How did you run the script? What does your command line looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Using a single `-` denotes a flag which is only single character. Your `-cn` will always be interpreted as two flags `-c` and `-n`.

The Python manual actually doesn't state this, at the time of this writing. This is the behaviour of `getopt` and a POSIX standard, as it would seem.

From [what I believe is the standard document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02)

> Guideline 3:
> Each option name should be a single alphanumeric character (the alnum character classification) from the portable character set. The -W (capital-W) option shall be reserved for vendor options.
> Multi-digit options should not be allowed.
>
> Guideline 4:
> All options should be preceded by the '-' delimiter character.

Apparently, when using a single hyphen `-`, we call the parameter an option and they are always single character. When using double hypen `--` we call the parameter and argument and they can have longer names.

---

Edit 1:

Argparse does not use getopt and I wasn't able to find any claim that argparse wants to work like getopt. It just happens to work like getopt.

---

Edit 2:
It would seem `argparse` let's you specify short options with more than one character but then only uses the first character.

```
import argparse
x = argparse.ArgumentParser()
x.add_argument('-fo', action='store', dest='fstore')

y = x.parse_args(['-f', 'foo'])

print(y)
```

does actually print `Namespace(fstore='foo')` on Python 3.11.2. It appears argparse is a bit overly tollerant when defining options.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax) does state this: "Several short options can be joined together, using only a single `-` prefix, as long as only the last option (or none of them) requires a value:"

Comment: @blhsing and actually the lines above say "short options (options only one character long)" and " long options (options with names longer than a single character)". Once you know what you are looking for it is easy enough to find two thirds into the page...

Comment: `argparse` does not enforce the `-c` (single character) pattern, but it is best to stick with it.  Otherwise it can be confused by its handling of abbreviations, and chaining.

Comment: To add: this is so you can set multiple options quickly, like: `foo -abhnd`, instead of `foo -a -b -h -n -d`. These are very old POSIX (?) conventions.